# Compilation error in IEEE format latex file

Tags: overleaf, compilation-error, ieee-style

So I am writing a latex code based on IEEE format , the format does not support jpeg or Png options , I  uploaded the files in eps format. Earlier when there was only one picture it was compiling fine , but after adding 4 more pics now its showing compilation errors. I am using Overleaf.
[image: Here]

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEphot}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\title{My title}

\author{The authors}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
 
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Some keywords
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}

A beautilful introduction

\section{Some title}

Some text

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=6cm, width=7.5cm]{image2_w.eps}\\
    \caption{A nice caption}
\end{center}

Some more text

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[height=7cm, width=7.5cm]{Screenshot (32).eps}\\
    \caption{Figure 2: PWE method algorithm }\\
    \includegraphics[height=7cm, width=7.5cm]{Screenshot (42).eps}\\
    \caption{Figure 3: RCWA method algorithm }
\end{center}

\section{Yet another title}

And still more text

\section{Results}

And again

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{bndsqr.eps}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{efieldMoneptfive.eps}\hfil
    \\[\smallskipamount]
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{efieldtauoneptfive.eps}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=.24\textwidth]{efieldXoneptfive.eps}
    \\[\smallskipamount]

    Now, we have plotted the transmission vs wavelength plot for three different radii (R = 0.25a, 0.3a, and 0.35a) and for five different refractive indices (n = 1,1.33,1.4,1.5,1.6). 
    The graphs are given below,
    \\
    From these graphs, we have noted the points for resonance by taking into account all of the refractive indices. From the information on these points, we have plotted the wavelength vs refractive index plot.
    The graph is shown below,

    \caption{Some images}\label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}

Final text

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It seems weird that `.jpg` and `.png` are not supported. What compiler is used for your document? (click on Menu on top left and give the element written in the Compiler field)

Comment: you are not getting a latex error but a system timeout so there is not much we can say here.  Unrelated but `includegraphics[height=7cm, width=7.5cm]{Screenshot (42).eps}` will distort the image, better to use just one of height or width

Comment: but if you use pdflatex (the default) rather than latex, you can use jpg or pdf or png rather  than eps

Comment: I had changed the and checked did not worked

Comment: I had to change the IEEE format to one which accepts jpg format pics. 
Thanks everyone the issue resolved